# Space between table rows with black border

Tags: html, border-spacing, border-collapse

I have a table in which I want space between rows and a black border around each row

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  border-spacing: 0 5px !important;
}

.table tr {
  border: 1px solid #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-borderless">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- `border-collapse = collapse` : Each row has a black border but no space between rows

[image]

- `border-collapse = separate` : The are space between rows but no black border around each row

[image]

if I remove `border-collapse` from css, it behaves exactly like the first image. How can I combine the two together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this be ok?

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  border-spacing: 0 5px !important;
}

.table tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.spacer { border-left:none !important;  height:20px }
```

```html
<table class="table table-borderless">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes it worked. I had to replace `border-left` to `border` in `spacer` class. Thanks